# MySQL not exists unknown column error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

for a couple of hours I have been working on this problem.

I have a table in MySQL called person_state

```
----------
person_state
----------------------------
id | person_id | state | date
----------------------------
```

I need to get **active persons last activation dates**, The state of every person is has been changed many times(States are  : active, passive, waiting, blocked). If a person is activated then deactivated, my query should not get it.

My query is

```
select id as activation_id, person_id as active_person_id
  from person_state
  where state = 'active' 
  and
  not exists(
         select * from person_state 
         where person_id = active_person_id
         and
         id > activation_id
    )
```

I am getting error ***Unknown column 'active_person_id' in 'where clause'*** .

Thanks for your your time

Comment: Use table aliases.

Comment: i think you are asking the wrong sql to the database i think you need something more like `GROUP BY person_id HAVING SUM(state = 'active') = 1 AND SUM(state = 'passive') = 0`... But iam not sure and cant test it without example data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` gets executed before `SELECT` and hence, you can't use column aliases inside it, try with column name instead, e.g.:

```
select id as activation_id, person_id as active_person_id
  from person_state ps
  where state = 'active' 
  and
  not exists(
         select id from person_state 
         where person_id = ps.person_id
         and
         id > ps.activation_id
    )
```

Comment: @Ali insan - do not use * in the select. you can use **SELECT 1** that is much faster

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query

```
select P.id as activation_id, P.person_id as active_person_id
  from person_state P
  where state = 'active' 
  and
  not exists(
         select 1 from person_state 
         where person_id = P.active_person_id
         and
         id > P.activation_id
    );
```

You have missed to provide alias. You can either give 1 or * to select the date. But 1 works faster as it checks for exists and it search only for one column

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have more than one column in a table, you should use qualified column names:

```
select ps.id as activation_id, ps.person_id as active_person_id
from person_state ps
where ps.state = 'active' and
      not exists (select *
                  from person_state ps2
                  where ps2.person_id = ps.person_id and
                        ps2.id > ps.id
                 ) ;
```

Your main problem is that you cannot use the column aliases in the subquery.